# Print in Swift 3

Tags: swift, printing

i would like to know what's the different between these two way to print the object in Swift.
The result seems identical.

```
var myName : String = "yohoo" 
print ("My name is \(myName).")

print ("My name is ", myName, ".")
```

Comment: One difference is they don't output the same thing – `My name is yohoo.` vs. `My name is  yohoo .` ;) (there's also double space between "is" and "yohoo" in the latter which isn't rendering here)

Comment: Hint: in Xcode, do CMD+click on `print`, you will get the header and very interesting information related to your question. It shows why `print` can accept one or several parameters.

Comment: Thanks guys!
I am new to Swift and there is a lot more for me to learn.
Any videos / tutorials / or topic that i should focus first?
I have been working on Objective C for a few months.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is almost no functional difference, the comma simply inputs a space either before or after the string.

```
let name = "John"

// both print "Hello John"
print("Hello", name)
print("Hello \(name)")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\(variable)` syntax to create interpolated strings, which are then printed just as you input them. However, the `print(var1,var2)` syntax has some "facilities":

- It automatically adds a space in between each two variables, and that is called `separator`
- You can customise your separator based on the context, for example:

  ```
  var hello = "Hello"
  var world = "World!"
  print(hello,world,separator: "|")    // prints "Hello|World!"
  print(hello,world,separator: "\\//")    // prints "Hello\\//World!"
  ```

Answer (score -1):

No difference between the two

```
var favoriteFood: String = "Pizza" //favoriteFood = Pizza

//both print the same thing
print("My favorite food is", favoriteFood)
print("My favorite food is \(favoriteFood)")
```

Comment: Without an explanation *how* they `print the same thing` *here*, this answer is *not useful*.