# Difference between Swift String Interpolation Prints

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development, while I was going through string interpolation. I want to know the clarification between these print statement's output:

```
var value = "5"
print("Values is: \(value)")
print("Values is:", value)
print("Values is: " + value)

Output is : Values is: 5
Values is: 5
Values is: 5
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963356/print-in-swift-3

Comment: It's important to note that you should generally avoid the `+` form. While a single `+` like this is usually fine, if you begin to chain them like `"name: " + name + ", value: " + value`, you can dramatically increase compile times (sometimes by orders of magnitude). The Swift compiler has a very hard time dealing with multiple + operators in a single expression because there are so many overloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a question, we should take a look at [`print(_:separator:terminator:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) parameters:

**1)** `items`: is a *variadic* parameter of type `Any`, which means that you can pass zero or more items to it. Example:

```
print() // passing nothing
print("Hello") // passing single item (String)
print(101, 40.45, false, ["Hi", "Greetings"]) // passing multiple items
```

**2)** `separator`: the string to print between each item *(as mentioned in its documentation)*. Example:

```
print(101, 40.45, false, ["Hi", "Greetings"], separator: " <=> ")
// 101<=>40.45<=>false<=>["Hi", "Greetings"]
```

**3)** `terminator`: the string to print after all items have been printed *(as mentioned in its documentation)*. Example:

```
print(101, 40.45, false, ["Hi", "Greetings"], terminator: " ==>")
// 101 40.45 false ["Hi", "Greetings"] ==>
```

---

**Back to your cases:**

First, keep in mind that for all of your three cases you are passing only `items` parameter; It is valid -for sure- because `separator` and `terminator` have default values as `" "` and `\n`.

Now, for the **first** and **third** print statements

```
print("Values is: \(value)")
print("Values is: " + value)
```

what happens is: actually you are dealing with `Strings`, it is not about the `print` itself. You can do interpolation in strings as well as using the `+` for concatenating strings without the `print`:

```
// interpolation:
let name = "Jack"
let greetingMessage = "Greetings, \(name)"
print(greetingMessage) // => Greetings, Jack

// concatenating:
let concatenated = "Greetings" + ", " + "Sara"
print(concatenated) // => "Greetings" + ", " + "Sara"
```

Which means that you are passing a *single* `String` item, regardless of doing interpolation or concatenation for it.

<sub>You could also check [The `+` function implementation in Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L565). Basically, it is an `append`!</sub>

The **second** `print` statement:

```
print("Values is:", value)
```

What happens here is: you are passing *two* items; According to the default value for `separator`, the output is:

> Values is: 5

As:

```
Values is: 5
     ^    ^^
     |    ||__ item #2
 item #1  |
          |
   default separator (" ")
```

Comment: Thanks :) for your detailed clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Practically all three forms do the same thing.

The differences are

1. String interpolation syntax. You can put everything within the inner parentheses which responds to the [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) protocol.
2. *Variadic* parameter syntax. `print` is declared `func print(_ items: Any...,`. `Any...` means you can pass multiple items comma separated which are treated as array.
3. String concatenation syntax : The strings are concatenated with the `+` operator

If `5` was `Int` rather than `String` forms 1 and 2 are valid but not form 3

Comment: And 2. is doing either 1. or 3. "inside". And worth noting, that 1. and 3. can be used not just to make string to display immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In this print statement output is the same but there is different like in first statement use `\(value)` variable within the string data.

The second statement append data in your string value **with keep one space**

The third statement just concat two value (it does not keep space between two value), In this statement "+" sign used as operator overloading to concat two value

```
let value = "5"
print("Values is: \(value)") //use variable value within string
print("Values is:", value)   //append value, with keep one space
print("Values is: " + value) //just concat two value
```

Answer (score 0):

var value = "5"

**print("Values is: (value)")** 
// Print the value as a part of the the string. If you use print("Values is:(value)"), it will print the output without space.

**print("Values is:", value)** 
// you do not need to add a separate space to add the value to sting. It will automatically add the value to the string with a space.

**print("Values is: " + value)** 
// It will show error if you use **integer** value "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'"

otherwise it will work. And if you want to concatenate int with sting you need to do something like below:-

**print("Values is: " + String(value))** 
// it is normal concatenate number with string

All the above will print the exact